# Requisições múltiplas de acessos a um mesmo método

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

Tenho uma aplicação executando com múltiplos logins usando um mesmo banco de dados para todos os acessos. Tenho tido um problema de requisição múltipla, dois usuários em locais distintos disparam a mesma requisição, porém preciso que executem o método um de cada vez. Existe algum recurso no Asp .Net Core que me ajude nisso? Disparo a requisição a partir da view usando ajax.

Comment: Coloque um exemplo mínimo!

Comment: @Larissa Vesper poste seu código para poder te ajudar.